# Unit test C# Error: The Method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm having trouble running unit test, it's returning the error "System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented." when arriving at the GetAll method in the repository

```
public partial class TestdbContext : DbContext 
    {
        public TestdbContext(){}
        public TestdbContext(DbContextOptions<TestdbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        
        public virtual DbSet<Car> Car { get; set; }
      
    

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {

            foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries<Entidade>())
            {
                switch (entity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entity.Entity.DataAlteracao = SystemClock.Now;
                        entity.Entity.UsuarioAlteracao= "teste";

                        break;
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entity.Entity.DataCriacao = SystemClock.Now;
                        entity.Entity.UsuarioCriacao = "teste";

                        break;
                }
            }

            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
public class CarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
        private readonly TestDbContext _dbContext;

        public CarRepository(TestDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }



        public void Add(Car car) => _dbContext.Cars.Add(car);


        public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetAll() => await _dbContext.Cars.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Class Tests

```
[TestFixture(Description = "")]
    public class CarRepositoryTests 
    {
        private Mock<TestDbContext> _dbContextMock = new Mock<TestDbContext>();
        private Mock<DbSet<Car>> _dbSetMock;
        private ICarRepository _repository;

        [Test]
        public async Task GetAll()
        {
            _dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<Car>>();
            var car = FakersEntidade.ObterFakerCar().Generate();

            var requisicaoCar = new List<Car>() { car }.AsQueryable();

            _dbContextMock = new Mock<TestDbContext>();
            _dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Cars).Returns(_dbSetMock.Object);

            MockFactory.CreateDbContextMock(_dbSetMock, requisicaoCar);

            _repository = new CarRepository(_dbContextMock.Object);

            var cars =  await _repository.GetAll();
            Assert.IsNotNull(cars);
        }

   

    }

 public static class MockFactory
    {
        public static void CreateDbContextMock<T>(Mock<DbSet<T>> mockDbSet, IQueryable<T> query) where T : class
        {
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(query.Provider);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(query.Expression);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(query.ElementType);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(query.GetEnumerator());
        }
    }



 public class Car: 
    {
        public Car(){}

        public string Cod{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public static readonly Car Default = new Car()
        {
            Cod = default,
            Name = string.Empty
        };

       
    }
```

Error (System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.) happens when reaching the CarRepository class -> the GetAll Method

Comment: Please review [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question. In particular make sure `MockFactory.CreateDbContextMock` is provided. Also you may want to explain what you expect to happen as result of ` _dbContextMock = new Mock<TestDbContext>();`.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the exception is thrown at

await _repository.GetAll();

so, in:

public async Task<IEnumerable> GetAll() => await _dbContext.Cars.ToListAsync();

How is the Cars property set up?

_dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Cars).Returns(_dbSetMock.Object);

So, ToListAsync() is called on a mock.

It seems that _dbSetMock needs a setup of ToListAsync().